# Changing v-model attribute name in Vue components

Tags: vue.js

We're creating an in-house web development framework in our company. We're in the process of creating a component library on top of Vue. Later some other web development frameworks are going to be supported, like React. etc.
We do this by encapsulating simple form controls in our own Vue components and use them like this in templates:

```
<our-input v-model="customerModel" />
```

What we want to do is, rename the "v-model" prop name to something else, to further abstract away any references to Vue so we can switch to another framework easily.

Any ideas of how to do it other that search and replace?

Answer (score 13):

In Vuejs 2.2 you can now rename value to some other property [(source)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#model)

Inside component:

```
Vue.component('OurInput', {
  model: {
    prop: 'customer',
    event: 'change'
  },
  props: {
    // use `customer` as the prop to take the place of `value`
    customer: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return {};
      }
    }
  },
  // ...
})
```

Two way binding using v-model:

```
<our-input v-model="customerModel" />
```

Two way binding without using v-model :

```
<our-input :customer="customerModel" @change="val => { customer = val }"/>
```

Don't forget to emit change event inside component or just use field input event instead:

```
this.$emit('close');
```

Comment: What are you aiming to with "default: () { return {}; }"?? -- It gives an error, and is not required for this (nice) setup to work.

Comment: @svenema good catch I fixed ES6 syntax for that default value. That colon shouldn't be there but for eslint purposes default values should be a function. See [vue/require-valid-default-prop] (https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/require-valid-default-prop.html) for the rule. Per organization guidelines, we explicitly state default values even if they are empty but it is not needed to run.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that cant be done as `v-model` is built in directive provided by vue.

But since `v-model` is nothing more than binding the input `value` and adding an event listener on the input to listen for any update and update the `value` of the input.

so:

```
<our-input v-model="customerModel" />
```

is same as:

```
<our-input :value="customerModel"  @input="value => { customerModel = value }">/>
```

Maybe this could help you. Fore more details see [custom component input handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events)

Comment: Thanks for the help. If I use v-model and emit 'input' event from my custom component than two-way binding works on the parent component. If I apply the code in the link you provided, I need to explicitly handle the emitted event on the parent, which kind of breaks automatic two-way binding.

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit but thats what `v-model` directive is also doing behind the scenes...its just syntactic sugar